# Visual Studio 2008 Visual Basic Database Connection Failed (Server/Instance)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

My Codes:

```
 sqlConn = New SqlConnection
            sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxxx\SQL2017;Initial Catalog=MCP;Integrated Security=False;User id=sa;Password=as;"
            sqlConn.Open()
```

This is not working.Prevent the "\" character program from running

Comment: I'm assuming you mean VB.NET since VBA is Office and not Visual Studio. Please take care when tagging to use the correct tags. Beside being courteous to others on the site it will also help you get assistance more quickly.

Comment: Are you using the correct user name and password? That password looks... odd.

Comment: What does `This is not working` mean? Do you get an error? What does it say? Wrong password? Wrong server? Did you forget to escape the `\ ` character perhaps? In C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript, VB.NET `\ ` is used an an escape character and needs to be escaped itself. You need to write `\\ ` each time you want to insert a single `\`

Comment: Are the server and instance names correct? Is the server running? If you get an error saying the server can't be found it means you either used the wrong name or the server isn't running. Or it isn't configured to allow remote connections. There are a lot of duplicate questions that explain how to solve this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 

Error:

Specified SQL server not found OTOKODSERVER\SQL2017

I tried \\ characters in connection string but not working.

Comment: @KaanErhan if the server isn't named like this, you can't connect to it. Have you tried to connect using SSMS?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - VB.Net doesn't use \ as an escape character.